# Disable out-of-the-box Fan Control in Ubuntu

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, fan, fancontrol

I am having issues with the out-of-the-box Fan Control in Ubuntu. After about 2 minutes after booting up the laptop, the fans start spinning on full speed. I tried Debian too, but there this didn't happen so it seems its an Ubuntu related issue. Thats why I would like to know how to disable the built in fan control and let the BIOS Fan Controller do his job.

The Device I'm talking of is an ASUS ROG GL502VT Laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issue was related to the Ubuntu Kernel. If anyone has an simlar issue with an Skylake Device, try to update to a newer Kernel Version like 4.6. Read here how to do so: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has no built-in fan control so your BIOS is already controlling the fan.

Your laptop has the HM170 chip-set. The manual for this is available [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/100-series-chipset-datasheet-vol-1.html). This states that the chip-set has a built-in fan speed controller that is capable of reading the speeds of up to 8 fans and controlling the speeds of up to 4 fans. There is also an on-chip temperature sensor. This can be used to read the temperature of the chip itself. However it has another mode in which it creates an interrupt when the temperature goes above a certain level called "hot" and the BIOS can use this to turn the fan on. It will not generate another interrupt until the temperature drops below "cool" and this will turn the fan off. It therefore sounds like the fan is operating exactly as intended. The values of "hot" and "cool" are set by the BIOS.

If the fan is coming on under Ubuntu but not for example Debian I would suggest installing `lm-sensors` and `P-Sensors` or `XSensors` and monitoring the utilisation and temperatures of the CPU and GPU to see what is getting hot.

Although the datasheet states that the temperature sensor can be read it does not indicate that any fan speed can so I do not think you are going to be able to control the fan speed using a program like Fancontrol.

Comment: It's not like that the fan slowly spins up. It's idle for about 2 minutes before boot and then it just goes full speed. So it seems the system just know 2 states, idle or 100%, when I installed fancontrol it was giving back a fan speed of 255 and it wasn't working because there was no fan speed reading. The CPU Temperature is about 35° after the fans started running full speed, so I don't think the temperature is causing the fans to run at full speed. One thing that might be a problem is that the FAN reading returns 25500 RPM at PSensors.

Comment: I think the issue would be fixable by getting fancontrol to work, but the problem is that the FanSpeed reading under Ubuntu is incorrect, could the HM170 Chipset be the Problem?

Answer (score 0):

After checking your laptop specification, I noticed that it came with an Intel Skylake processor. I've seen people reporting this kind of fan issue against Skylake CPU on launchpad.net and the issue is just identical to what you described here: the fan keeps running in full speed even the system is cool.

It looks like it can be solved (at least on a Lenovo X1) by upgrading the Intel Management Engine Interface (IMEI) firmware. Please follow the links below for discussions.

(Also, don't forget you can file a new bug for it!)

Reference:

- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/293087
- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-certification/+question/293705
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1579917

Comment: Thanks for this information. Filed a bug at launchpad. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1607783

Comment: Also it seems the issue is only occuring on default bootup, but nomodeset seems to prevent it.